# Owl Carousel, why page is postback on navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel on a page for slider autoplay as well as for next and previous slides. Everything is working fine as expected. but the thing is whenever I am hitting next or prev button, the page is doing post back and loading everything again.

**Is there any way to stop that post back?**

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            Items: 1,
            Autoplay: true,
            AutoplayTimeout: 5000,
            AutoplayHoverPause: true,
            Loop: true,
            Nav: true,
        });
    });

Comment: Here, I am using Autoplay as well as navigation. For that, i am using owl.carousel.js and owl.autoplay.js.

I am using this for a SharePoint Visual Web Part.

If you need full HTML, drop me your ID/Skype.. will forward the ZIP.

Comment: please update your post and if you could, create a fiddle for that